# Confusion with Linux find regex

Tags: find, regular-expression

I'm getting quite confused with Linux `find` command's regular expression usage.

I'm aware that there is an option `regextype`, but without that, according to the current man page, it is supposed to use Emacs regular expressions.  [This page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special) seems to say that character classes are supported ("this is a POSIX feature"), but my experiments seem to show that nothing like `[[:ascii:]]` or `[[:digit:]]` or `[[:alnum:]]` ever works, quite apart from the fact that these are truly archaic ways of handling characters classes. Instead you seem to have to use `[a-zA-Z]` which, apart from anything else, is useless for Unicode characters.

So I turned to `regextype`: I find that you get a list of possible settings by going `find -regextype help`.  This gives:

```
find: Unknown regular expression type ‘help’; valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘awk’, ‘egrep’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’.
```

... so I assumed that by including `-regextype posix-basic`, for example, I'd be able to run something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-basic -regex .*\d.*
```

This produces results, but not the ones I was hoping for: all the files and folders in the current directory with the lower-case letter "d" in their names! I was expecting all names with at least one digit.

I've looked at quite a lot of Linux `find` regex questions here on Stack Exchange, but I don't think I've seen a single one where "modern" character class handling is demonstrated. Is any of the `regextype` options able to handle something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype ??? -regex '.*\d{3}\s+.*'
```

where I mean "contains three digits followed by one or more empty space characters". I.e. something like regex rules from a normal language like Java, Python, Javascript, etc...?

***later, following comments***

Here's an exercise: make a directory and put a few files into it with random names.  Then added files with the following names: 'ctb117b', 'ctb117c', 'trt117a'.

I then want to isolate the '117' files. There may be files called 'xxx0009333qqq'. So using a modern regex engine I'd go like this, for example (allowing for the preceding ./):

```
find . -regex './\w{3}\d\{3}.*'
```

Using these more venerable Linux regex rules, what do I put that works?

```
find . -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*[[:digit:]]{3}.*'
```

produces nothing. Nor does `'.*[[:digit:]]+.*'`, for example. If anyone's sufficiently interested, please show me something which works for you (lists the above files).

Comment: `\d` is a Perl-like expression, also supported by some GNU tools as a short way of writing what would be written as `[[:digit:]]` in a POSIX expression. Same for `\s` (`[[:blank:]]`).  The `{3}` modifier is a POSIX extended expression modifier.

Comment: When using `*`, be sure to quote it. `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-basic -regex .*\d.*` probably gave you unexpected results because `*\d.*` matched something in the current directory, so the shell expanded it before `find` ever saw your regex.

Comment: `[[:digit:]]` works with all `posix-*` `-regextype`, and also with other (`egrep`, etc).

Comment: You could use `-name '*[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:blank:]]*'`

Comment: @AndyDalton I just tried that command with first single quotes and then double quotes. Both returned the same (wrong) results.

Comment: I am having no luck whatsoever with [[:digit:]]... in particular, surely [[:digit:]]+ is meant to mean "one or more digit(s)", and [[:digit:]]{3} is meant to mean "precisely three digits".  This functionality is NOT working for me. I'm going to add an "exercise" at the end of my question for anyone sufficiently interested.

Comment: Where does the `find` command that you are using come from? Did you build it yourself from sources?

Comment: @Kusalananda No! This is a standard Linux Mint (18.3) OS. I have not fiddled with the BASH in any way.  It is version 4.3.48.

Comment: use `posix-extended` instead of `posix-basic`. Neither `+` nor the  `{3}` repetition works in BRE (basic regular expressions).

Comment: But it seems that you're confused about what you're looking for: the `^\w{3}\d{3}.*$` PCRE-like regex example you're giving (I've removed the extra backslash) will also match the `xxx0009333qqq`, not just the `ctb117b`, etc.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks, that's a useful piece of info. Yes, you're right about the example "other file", apologies. I'm looking for 3 non-digits, followed by 3 digits, followed by anything. So the "other file" was a bad example.

Comment: Which `find`?, run `find --version`. Linux does not have a find. Linux is just a kernel. Used is several Operating Systems: e.g. Gnu/Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using this :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[[:digit:]]{3}\s+.*'
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. Firstly it produced no results, but that wouldn't be surprising, as there are no spaces in the names of the files (see suggested exercise). If I drop the `\s+` things get listed. But explain this: if I put `'.*[[:digit:]]{80}.*'` it returns exactly the same files! It completely ignores the "number of matches" directive!

Comment: In your post, you said "contains three digits followed by one or more empty space characters". Are you sure you get same files when you put `'.*[[:digit:]]{80}.*'` and `-regextype posix-extended` ?

Comment: Sorry, no... I've got that wrong.  The {80} directive is working as expected.  Apologies. By the way, are you saying that backslash character classes work with posix-extended?  So should "\w" work? I find that it does... but './\w{3}\d{3}.*' doesn't... I must find the right documentation for posix-extended obviously!

Comment: \w does not work with posix-extended

Comment: It seems to: `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex './\w{3}[[:digit:]]{3}.*'` ... lists the right files.  From the source: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax.html ... "\w" is one character class listed there.

Comment: Yes, you are right, posix-extended does accept \w

Comment: You've really clarified things for me... thanks.

Comment: Nitpick: `\w`, `\d`, `\s` etc. are _not_ POSIX extended regular expression things, but GNU's _implementation_ of POSIX extended regular expressions includes them (for convenience). They are originally from Perl.

Comment: @Kusalananda  YES! Thanks for that. I took the trouble of examining that page... "\w" is said to be "matches a character within a word", which is not the same as "matches a letter"! Also that page does not list the "\s" matcher.  All quite confusing.  PS isn't it time someone upgraded find and other commands so they can use a more modern, and hopefully uniform, regex set of rules?

Comment: @mikerodent That's a sloppy way of saying "matches a _word character_", i.e. it's the same as `[[:alnum:]_]` (alphanumerics and underscore). That's what `\w` matches in Perl.

Comment: Strange, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html#boost_regex.syntax.basic_extended.escapes_matching_a_specific_character  says \w is included

Comment: @mikerodent Also read the section above that.