# regex pattern for find to remove conflict files from git

Tags: find, regular-expression

I am trying to create a find command to find the files that git create when there is a conflicting rebase/merge.

```
.//Tools/tri_tri_intersect.h
.//Tools/tri_tri_intersect.cpp
.//Collisions/PBD/FiltersUtils_BACKUP_450361.cpp
.//Collisions/PBD/FiltersUtils_BASE_450361.cpp
.//Collisions/PBD/FiltersUtils_LOCAL_450361.cpp
.//Collisions/PBD/FiltersUtils_REMOTE_450361.cpp
```

From this list of files, I want a find command to select the last 4, the ones with BACKUP, LOCAL, REMOTE, BASE.

I have tried this `find . -type f -regex '.+_((BACKUP)|(BASE)|(LOCAL)|(REMOTE))_.*'` but doesn't work.

What would be the correct regex?

Comment: Add `-regextype egrep` to your command.

Comment: That worked. Can you explain the difference between adding it and not adding it?

Comment: At least for the GNU implementation, the default regextype is `emacs` - which supports an ERE-style `+` quantifier, but grouping and alternation must be escaped like POSIX BRE: `'.+_\(BACKUP\|BASE\|LOCAL\|REMOTE\)_.*'`. See also [Confusion with Linux find regex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560896/confusion-with-linux-find-regex)

Comment: ... but personally I'd probably avoid the confusion by sticking with standard glob patterns: `find . -type f \( -name '*_BACKUP_*' -o -name '*_BASE_*' -o -name '*_LOCAL_*' -o -name '*_REMOTE_*' \)`

Comment: So there are some webpages that allow to test regex patterns. https://regexr.com/ or https://regex101.com/. I like them because they also teach what is each part of the regex doing, useful for debug it. But how can I know is they are emac, ERE, Posix BRE?

Comment: @jjcasmar it's complicated - see for example [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)